# angularjs ng-flow message not show up

Tags: angularjs, ng-flow

I am currently working on the ng-flow plugin, the code below is copy from quick setup for ng-flow (website reference: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow)

```html
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload'}"
     flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"
     flow-file-success="$file.msg = $message">

  <input type="file" flow-btn/>
  Input OR Other element as upload button
  <span class="btn" flow-btn>Upload File</span>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.msg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The `$index+1` and `file.name` is showing up, however the `file.msg` does not show anything. Can anyone explain this problem to me?

Comment: message contains the server response, are you sure that your server is sending it?

Comment: Maybe there is no response from server? Because I assume that what file.msg is. A response after uploading a file.

Comment: may i know how to get the response from server

Comment: So you are uploading your file to the server. In your case server should expose "/upload" endpoint which will accept your file and respond with some message.

Comment: Thanks for reply, btw i would like to know by using ng-flow, is it possible to get the full path of the image uploaded (such as C:/desktop/folder/image.png), all i get from ng-flow is only the image name (such as image.png), even relative path also shows only the image name, i would like to know is it possible to get the full path of it? thanks